# Extract text from PDF in respect to formatting (font size, type etc)

Tags: pdf, fonts, extract, font-size

Is possible to extract text from a PDF file concerning specific font/font size/font colour etc.? I prefer Perl, python or *nix command-line utilities. My goal is to extract all headlines from PDF file so I will have a nice index of articles contained in a single PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text and /font/font size/position (no color, as I checked) you can get from Ghostscript's txtwrite device (try -dTextFormat=0 | 1 options), as well as from mudraw's (MuPDF) with -tt option. Then parse XML-like output with e.g. Perl.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Seems that mudraw is the way. One thing that I don't like is the fact that I cannot disable converting the images, I get bunch of the encoded images starting with `<img width=803 height=1155 src="data:image/png;base64` It's not a bug, it's a feature, but I don't need pictures in my case, and assume it will be faster to process only text no images. Also I am wondering to try ghostscript advise, can you be more specific how to do it? Many thanks.

Comment: @WakanTanka, try mudraw with -ttt argument (and -x also worth exploring), then there are no images in the output, but text information is presented slightly different. Ghostscript, for your purpose, can be used like this: `gs -sDEVICE=txtwrite -dTextFormat=0 -o out.txt in.pdf` or -dTextFormat=1. Output's not "txt", it's xml-ish like mudraw with -ttt option.

Comment: I have tried ghostsript (both 0 and 1) and it gives me error. `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` maybe I am using old version on older Fedora (found that this is know bug). Anyway output looks similar to using `mudraw -ttt or mudraw -x` options (as if every single character is one element). Seems that `mudraw -tt` is the way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

I have working code which extracts text from pdf with the size of the font.
with help of PDfminer, I have achieved this job. with many pdf's

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer, LTChar,LTLine,LAParams
import os
path=r'path\whereyour pdffile'
os.chdir(path)
Extract_Data=[]
for PDF_file in os.listdir():
    if PDF_file.endswith('.pdf'):
       for page_layout in extract_pages(PDF_file):
            for element in page_layout:
                if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
                    for text_line in element:
                        for character in text_line:
                            if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                                Font_size=character.size
                    Extract_Data.append([Font_size,(element.get_text())])
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used `fitz` to accomplish the required task, as it is much faster compared to `pdfminer`. You can find my duplicate answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71750693/18391419).
An example code snippet is shown below.

```py
import fitz

def scrape(keyword, filePath):
    results = [] # list of tuples that store the information as (text, font size, font name) 
    pdf = fitz.open(filePath) # filePath is a string that contains the path to the pdf
    for page in pdf:
        dict = page.get_text("dict")
        blocks = dict["blocks"]
        for block in blocks:
            if "lines" in block.keys():
                spans = block['lines']
                for span in spans:
                    data = span['spans']
                    for lines in data:
                        if keyword in lines['text'].lower(): # only store font information of a specific keyword
                            results.append((lines['text'], lines['size'], lines['font']))
                            # lines['text'] -> string, lines['size'] -> font size, lines['font'] -> font name
    pdf.close()
    return results
```

If you wish to find the font information of every line, you may omit the if condition that checks for a specific keyword.

You can extract the text information in any desired format by understanding the [structure of dictionary outputs](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/textpage.html#structure-of-dictionary-outputs) that we obtain by using `get_text("dict")`, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#extracting-text-and-images).

Comment: @Ethan thank you for suggesting the change, I have updated my answer. Please let me know any other changes that could improve the answer.