# PDF miner - extract font size?

Tags: python, pdf, fonts

I'm curious if it's possible to use pdfminer to extract font size. I think this would be helpful for separating out different sections. I know there's the discussion below, but I'm curious if it's possible to use pdfminer

[Extract text from PDF in respect to formatting (font size, type etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386711/extract-text-from-pdf-in-respect-to-formatting-font-size-type-etc)

the pdfminer documentation says it's possible http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/

but when i type in he following into the command line, i just get a plain text document. I don't see any font information.

```
pdf2txt.py -o output.html samples/CentolaCV.pdf
```

e.g...

```
2008-13  Assistant Professor, Sloan School of Management, M.I.T.  

2006-08   Robert Wood Johnson Scholar in Health Policy, Harvard University 

2001-02   Visiting Scholar, The Brookings Institution
```

Answer (score 5):

Try specifying the file output type with the `-t` flag:

`pdf2txt.py -o output.html -t html samples/CentolaCV.pdf`

That should return an html file with the style attributes font-family and font-size.

**EDIT**: actually, it looks like the output ending can specify the outfile type without the `-t` flag. Can you link to the pdf file that you're trying to extract font style from?

Comment: Is it possible to get font-weight too? I need the text in bold.

Answer (score 5):

This task was puzzling me for a long time. Next to extracting fonts-information I also wanted to run this code in a python script.

Hower, today I was able to solve it. Below I wrote a script that calls the `pdf2txt.py` script from the command line and then extracts the font-information form the parsed PDF and newly created html file.

```
import os

pathToScript = r'path\to\script\pdf2txt.py'
pathPDFinput = os.path.join(path\to\file, 'test.pdf')
pathHTMLoutput = os.path.join(path\to\file, 'test.html')

# call the pdf2txt.py from the command line
os.system('python {} -o {} -S {} -t html'.format(pathToScript, pathHTMLoutput, pathPDFinput))
```

Extract the font-size for every html tag:

```
# credits to akash karothiya: 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012739/need-to-extract-all-the-font-sizes-and-the-text-using-beautifulsoup/39015419#39015419

import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# open the html file
html = open(pathHTMLoutput, 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

font_spans = [data for data in soup.select('span') if 'font-size' in str(data)]
output = []
for span in font_spans:
    fonts_size = re.search(r'(?is)(font-size:)(.*?)(px)', str(span.get('style'))).group(2)
    fonts_family = re.search(r'(?is)(font-family:)(.*?)(;)', str(span.get('style'))).group(2)

    # split fonts_family into fonts-type and fonts-style
    try:
        fonts_type = fonts_family.strip().split(',')[0]
        fonts_style = fonts_family.strip().split(',')[1]
    except IndexError:
        fonts_type = fonts_family.strip()
        fonts_style = None

    output.append(
        (str(i.text).strip(), fonts_size.strip(), fonts_type, fonts_style)
    )

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = ['text', 'fonts-size', 'fonts-type', 'fonts-style'])
```