# Python - Extract formatted text (i.e. bold, italics, color) from pdf

Tags: python, pdf, formatting, extract

Are there any libraries for Python that allow extraction of text from PDFs, but preserve formatting (i.e. bold, italics, underline, color, etc)?

I've looked into options such as `pdfminer` but to the best of my knowledge they only extract raw text.

Comment: "The pdfminer documentation says it's possible" - http://stackoverflow.com/q/22329508/2564301

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.