# PDFminer: extract text with its font information

Tags: python, text-extraction, pdfminer

I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329508/pdf-miner-extract-font-size), but it uses command line, and I do not want to call a Python script in command line using subprocess and parse HTML files to get the font information.

I want to use PDFminer as a library, and I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725278/how-do-i-use-pdfminer-as-a-library), but they are just all about extracting plain texts, without other information such as font name, font size, and so on.

Comment: Very interesting question, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
import pdfminer


def createPDFDoc(fpath):
    fp = open(fpath, 'rb')
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    document = PDFDocument(parser, password='')
    # Check if the document allows text extraction. If not, abort.
    if not document.is_extractable:
        raise "Not extractable"
    else:
        return document


def createDeviceInterpreter():
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    return device, interpreter


def parse_obj(objs):
    for obj in objs:
        if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTTextBox):
            for o in obj._objs:
                if isinstance(o,pdfminer.layout.LTTextLine):
                    text=o.get_text()
                    if text.strip():
                        for c in  o._objs:
                            if isinstance(c, pdfminer.layout.LTChar):
                                print "fontname %s"%c.fontname
        # if it's a container, recurse
        elif isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTFigure):
            parse_obj(obj._objs)
        else:
            pass


document=createPDFDoc("/tmp/simple.pdf")
device,interpreter=createDeviceInterpreter()
pages=PDFPage.create_pages(document)
interpreter.process_page(pages.next())
layout = device.get_result()


parse_obj(layout._objs)
```

Comment: This works for getting the font name, but not font size or other attributes (italics, bold, etc.)

Comment: @Agargara did you find a way to get `font size` and perhaps other properties from pdf?

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya I ended up editing the pdfminer source to get the font size. See: https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues/202 However, note that this value still might not be the actual font size because of superscripts, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Full disclosure, I am one of the maintainers of [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six). It is a community-maintained version of pdfminer for python 3.

Nowadays, pdfminer.six has multiple API's to extract text and information from a PDF. For programmatically extracting information I would advice to use `extract_pages()`. This allows you to inspect all of the elements on a page, ordered in a meaningful hierarchy created by the layout algorithm.

The following example is a pythonic way of showing all the elements in the hierachy. It uses the [simple1.pdf](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/blob/develop/samples/simple1.pdf) from the samples directory of pdfminer.six.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable, Any

from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages


def show_ltitem_hierarchy(o: Any, depth=0):
    """Show location and text of LTItem and all its descendants"""
    if depth == 0:
        print('element                        fontname             text')
        print('------------------------------ -------------------- -----')

    print(
        f'{get_indented_name(o, depth):<30.30s} '
        f'{get_optional_fontinfo(o):<20.20s} '
        f'{get_optional_text(o)}'
    )

    if isinstance(o, Iterable):
        for i in o:
            show_ltitem_hierarchy(i, depth=depth + 1)


def get_indented_name(o: Any, depth: int) -> str:
    """Indented name of class"""
    return '  ' * depth + o.__class__.__name__


def get_optional_fontinfo(o: Any) -> str:
    """Font info of LTChar if available, otherwise empty string"""
    if hasattr(o, 'fontname') and hasattr(o, 'size'):
        return f'{o.fontname} {round(o.size)}pt'
    return ''


def get_optional_text(o: Any) -> str:
    """Text of LTItem if available, otherwise empty string"""
    if hasattr(o, 'get_text'):
        return o.get_text().strip()
    return ''


path = Path('~/Downloads/simple1.pdf').expanduser()
pages = extract_pages(path)
show_ltitem_hierarchy(pages)
```

The output shows the different elements in the hierarchy, the font name and size if available and the text that this element contains.

```
element                        fontname             text
------------------------------ -------------------- -----
generator                                           
  LTPage                                            
    LTTextBoxHorizontal                             Hello
      LTTextLineHorizontal                          Hello
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       H
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       e
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       o
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       
        LTAnno                                      
    LTTextBoxHorizontal                             World
      LTTextLineHorizontal                          World
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       W
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       o
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       r
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       d
        LTAnno                                      
    LTTextBoxHorizontal                             Hello
      LTTextLineHorizontal                          Hello
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       H
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       e
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       o
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       
        LTAnno                                      
    LTTextBoxHorizontal                             World
      LTTextLineHorizontal                          World
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       W
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       o
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       r
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       d
        LTAnno                                      
    LTTextBoxHorizontal                             H e l l o
      LTTextLineHorizontal                          H e l l o
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       H
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       e
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       o
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       
        LTAnno                                      
    LTTextBoxHorizontal                             W o r l d
      LTTextLineHorizontal                          W o r l d
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       W
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       o
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       r
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       d
        LTAnno                                      
    LTTextBoxHorizontal                             H e l l o
      LTTextLineHorizontal                          H e l l o
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       H
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       e
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       o
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       
        LTAnno                                      
    LTTextBoxHorizontal                             W o r l d
      LTTextLineHorizontal                          W o r l d
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       W
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       o
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       r
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       l
        LTAnno                                      
        LTChar                 Helvetica 24pt       d
        LTAnno
```

(Similar answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69962316/4054971),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69962482/4054971) and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69151177/4054971)
, I'll try to keep them in sync.)

Comment: What about "boldness" or "italicness", is information available about that? Sometimes you can get some info through the font name, but when font names are embedded in a PDF, they usually have coded names. So, how can we can we get information about "boldness" or "italicness" in a generic way from a PDF? (Other then using computer vision).

Answer (score 3):

This approach does not use PDFMiner but does the trick.

First, convert the PDF document into docx. Using [python-docx](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can then retrieve font information. Here's an example of getting all the bold text

```
from docx import *

document = Document('/path/to/file.docx')

for para in document.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        if run.bold:
            print run.text
```

If you really want to use PDFMiner you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5730942/7760998). Passing '-t' would convert the PDF into HTML with all the font information.

Comment: But, while converting PDF to docx, it may loose information of that?

Comment: Is there any reliable library for converting PDF to Docx?

Answer (score 3):

**I hope this could help you :)**

Get the font-family:

```
if isinstance(c, pdfminer.layout.LTChar):
    print (c.fontname)
```

Get the font-size:

```
if isinstance(c, pdfminer.layout.LTChar):
    print (c.size)
```

Get the font-positon:

```
if isinstance(c, pdfminer.layout.LTChar):
    print (c.bbox)
```

Get the info of image:

```
if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTImage):
outputImg = "<Image>\n"
outputImg += ("name: %s, " % obj.name)
outputImg += ("x: %f, " % obj.bbox[0])
outputImg += ("y: %f\n" % obj.bbox[1])
outputImg += ("width1: %f, " % obj.width)
outputImg += ("height1: %f, " % obj.height)
outputImg += ("width2: %f, " % obj.stream.attrs['Width'])
outputImg += ("height2: %f\n" % obj.stream.attrs['Height'])
print (outputImg)
```

Comment: Interesting, can you please provide full code snippet? The variable `c` is not understood.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the font size or font name from a PDF file using PDF miner library you have to interpret the whole pdf page. You should decide for which word, phrase do you want to get font size and font name(as on a page you can have multiple words with different font sizes). The structure using PDF miner for a page:
PDFPageInterpreter -> LTTextBox -> LTChar
Once you found out for which word you want to get font size you call:
size method for font size(which actually is height), and fontname for font.
Code should look like this, you pass the pdf file path, word for which you want to get font size and the page number(on which page is the searched word):

```
def get_fontsize_and_fontname_for_word(self, pdf_path, word, page_number):
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    layout_params = LAParams()
    device = PDFPageAggregator(resource_manager, laparams=layout_params)
    pdf_file = file(pdf_path, 'rb')
    pdf_page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, device)
    global actual_font_size_pt, actual_font_name

    for current_page_number, page in enumerate(PDFPage.get_pages(pdf_file)):
        if current_page_number == int(page_number) - 1:
            pdf_page_interpreter.process_page(page)
            layout = device.get_result()
            for textbox_element in layout:
                if isinstance(textbox_element, LTTextBox):
                    for line in textbox_element:
                        word_from_textbox = line.get_text().strip()
                        if word in word_from_textbox:
                            for char in line:
                                if isinstance(char, LTChar):
                                    # convert pixels to points
                                    actual_font_size_pt = int(char.size) * 72 / 96
                                    # remove prefixed font name, such as QTBAAA+
                                    actual_font_name = char.fontname[7:]
    pdf_file.close()
    device.close()
    return actual_font_size_pt, actual_font_name
```

You could check what other properties LTChar class supports

Comment: Can you please help me understand how have you arrived at the formula for calculating acutual_font_size_pt?

Comment: I've converted pixels to points, points = pixels * 72 / 96 , check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139655/convert-pixels-to-points

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PDFlib](http://www.pdflib.com/products/tet/features/), it can extract font info as you require and has a Python library you can import in your scripts and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Some informations are in lower level, in the LTChar class. It seems logic because font size, italic, bold, etc, can be applied to a single character.

More infos here : https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/pdfminer/layout.py#L222

But I'm still confuse about font color not in this class