# Wrong decoding of Devanagiri fonts when parsing PDFs

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, python-camelot

I am using [Camelot](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot) to parse budget documents released by different states in India. The parsing happens fine, but the output of the parsing for Devanagari (languages such as Hindi, Marathi, etc) are different from the ones in the document. The input file is on [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QrnXdTGk8n8TsohKRQ5u7guZKezJgcMt/view) link, and the output file after parsing is on [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kLinDfoek0n_RcVAMD1nrxuDebOh2BQk/view) link. As can be seen, the Devanagari characters don't correspond to that in the input file. A MWE is shown below.

```
import camelot
tables = camelot.read_pdf('Demand_ Estimate.pdf', flavor='stream')
tables[0].to_csv('demand_estimate.csv')
```

Comment: This is fairly common for pdfs in Indian languages, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35917848/1729265) and other questions linked from there.

Comment: Inspection of your example PDF shows that the issue at hand indeed is the same as in those duplicated questions - the **ToUnicode** tables of the fonts in it map multiple, different looking glyphs to the same Unicode code point. Thus, text extraction (which relies on those tables) will always return such broken results. As a test you can apply simple copy&paste from Adobe Reader which also in your case returns the same broken results. Unless you try to implement your very own text extractor (which tries to rely on other, usually otherwise meaningless information), you have to try OCR.

Comment: For anyone, who is interested, we managed to find a workaround by converting the pdf to an image and then obtain the csv file. It is something that might or might not work depending on the document. For us, it is working for most of our documents.

Comment: *"converting the pdf to an image and then obtain the csv file"* - That *obtaining* would be by means of OCR, I presume.

Comment: Yes. I should have added that. We used tesseract to do that