# Need to extract all the font sizes and the text using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, fonts, beautifulsoup

I have the following html file stored on my local system:

```
<span style="position:absolute; border: gray 1px solid; left:0px; top:50px; width:612px; height:792px;"></span>
<div style="position:absolute; top:50px;"><a name="1">Page 1</a></div>
<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:45px; top:71px; width:322px; height:38px;"><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:30px">One
<br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:45px; top:104px; width:175px; height:40px;"><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:15px">Two</span><span style="font-family: CAAAAA+DejaVuSans; font-size:16px">: two txt
<br></span><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:15px">Three</span><span style="font-family: CAAAAA+DejaVuSans; font-size:16px">: Three txt
<br></span><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:15px">Four</span><span style="font-family: CAAAAA+DejaVuSans; font-size:16px">: Four txt
<br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:274px; top:144px; width:56px; height:19px;"><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:19px">FIVE
<br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:45px; top:171px; width:515px; height:44px;"><span style="font-family: CAAAAA+DejaVuSans; font-size:18px">five txt
<br>five txt2 
<br>five txt3
<br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:220px; top:223px; width:164px; height:19px;"><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:19px">SIX
<br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:44px; top:247px; width:489px; height:159px;"><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:17px">six txt
<br></span><span style="font-family: CAAAAA+DejaVuSans; font-size:18px">six txt2
<br>- six txt2
<br>• six txt3
<br>• six txt4 
<br>• six txt5
<br></span>
```

I need to extract all the font-sizes that occur in this html file. I am using beautifulsoup, but I know only how to extract the text.

I can extract the text using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmlData = open('/home/usr/Downloads/files/output.html', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlData)

texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
```

I need to extract the font size of each piece of text and store the font-text pair into a list or array. To be specific, I want to have a data structure like `[('One','30'),('Two','15')]` and so on where 30 is from the `font-size:30px` and 15 from `font-size:15px`

The only problem is that I can't figure out a way to get the font-size value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps : I suggest you to read more documents on `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmlData = open('/home/usr/Downloads/files/output.html', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlData)

font_spans = [ data for data in soup.select('span') if 'font-size' in str(data) ]
output = []
for i in font_spans:
    tup = ()
    fonts_size = re.search(r'(?is)(font-size:)(.*?)(px)',str(i.get('style'))).group(2)
    tup = (str(i.text).strip(), fonts_size.strip())
    output.append(tup)

print(output)
[('One', '30'),('Two', '15'), ....]
```

If you want to eliminate text values which contains `txt` you may add `if not 'txt' in i.text:`

Explanation :

First you need to identify tags which contains `font-size`,

```
font_spans = [ data for data in soup.select('span') if 'font-size' in str(data) ]
```

Then you need to iterate `font_spans` and extract font-size and text value,

```
textvalue = i.text # One,Two..
fonts_size = re.search(r'(?is)(font-size:)(.*?)(px)',str(i.get('style'))).group(2) # 30, 15, 16..
```

and Finally you need to create a list which contains all your output as in tuples.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *css select* `select("[style*=font-size]")` to fing tags with a style attribute that contains *font-size* and use a regex to extract the value:

```
In [12]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [13]: import re

In [14]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [15]: patt = re.compile("font-size:(\d+)")

In [16]: [(tag.text.strip(), patt.search(tag["style"]).group(1)) for tag in soup.select("[style*=font-size]")]
Out[16]: 
[('One', '30'),
 ('Two', '15'),
 (': two txt', '16'),
 ('Three', '15'),
 (': Three txt', '16'),
 ('Four', '15'),
 (': Four txt', '16'),
 ('FIVE', '19'),
 ('five txt\nfive txt2\nfive txt3', '18'),
 ('SIX', '19'),
 ('six txt', '17'),
 ('six txt2\n- six txt2\n• six txt3\n• six txt4\n• six txt5', '18')]
```

Comment: this is more generic than the other answers

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some research for your self, the [beautiful soup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and the [regex doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) are something that you should read and understand how the things flow.

Check out the following example which using a regular expression to extract the **first** occurrence of the font-size and then splitted properly to get only the pixel numbers.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4 import Tag
import re

data = """
  <span style="position:absolute; border: gray 1px solid; left:0px; top:50px; width:612px; height:792px;"></span>
  <div style="position:absolute; top:50px;"><a name="1">Page 1</a></div>
  <div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:45px; top:71px; width:322px; height:38px;">
    <span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:30px">One
    <br></span>
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:45px; top:104px; width:175px; height:40px;"><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:15px">Two</span><span style="font-family: CAAAAA+DejaVuSans; font-size:16px">: two txt
  <br></span><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:15px">Three</span><span style="font-family: CAAAAA+DejaVuSans; font-size:16px">: Three txt
  <br></span><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:15px">Four</span><span style="font-family: CAAAAA+DejaVuSans; font-size:16px">: Four txt
  <br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:274px; top:144px; width:56px; height:19px;"><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:19px">FIVE
  <br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:45px; top:171px; width:515px; height:44px;"><span style="font-family: CAAAAA+DejaVuSans; font-size:18px">five txt
  <br>five txt2 
  <br>five txt3
  <br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:220px; top:223px; width:164px; height:19px;"><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:19px">SIX
  <br></span></div><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:44px; top:247px; width:489px; height:159px;"><span style="font-family: BAAAAA+DejaVuSans-Bold; font-size:17px">six txt
  <br></span><span style="font-family: CAAAAA+DejaVuSans; font-size:18px">six txt2
  <br>- six txt2
  <br> six txt3
  <br> six txt4 
  <br> six txt5
  <br></span>
"""
soup = Soup(data, 'html.parser')

def get_the_start_of_font(attr):
  """ Return the index of the 'font-size' first occurrence or None. """
  match = re.search(r'font-size:', attr)
  if match is not None:
    return match.start()
  return None 

def get_font_size_from(attr):
  """ Return the font size as string or None if not found. """
  font_start_i = get_the_start_of_font(attr)
  if font_start_i is not None:
    return str(attr[font_start_i + len('font-size:'):].split('px')[0])
  return None

# iterate through all descendants:
fonts = []
for child in soup.descendants:
  if isinstance(child, Tag) is True and child.get('style') is not None:
    font = get_font_size_from(child.get('style'))
    if font is not None:
      fonts.append([
        str(child.text).strip(), font])

print(fonts)
```

The solution can be improved, but this is a working example.

Comment: Thanks for the a2a. I'll surely read the documentation of BeautifulSoup and regex.